# Como criar TDataSetFields, no TFDMemTable, em tempo de execução

Tags: delphi, firedac

Com o ClientDataSet era possível trazer um campo TDataSetField com uma outra estrutura de dados (uma outra tabela) internamente. Isso era feito automaticamente pelo TDataSetProvider.

Estou migrando para FireDac e TFDMemTable, mas infelizmente ele parece não possuir esta mesma facilidade que o ClientDataSet (ainda que possua suporte a esse campo).
E eu preciso que ele sustente esta estrutura pois tenho mapeamentos baseado nisso.

Alguém saberia como criar este TDataSetField em tempo de execução?

Comment: É possível fazer com o FDMemTable, usando .Data, com ele tens a facilidade de copiar toda a estrutura (Fields) de um dataset (FDMemTable/TFDQuery) com as informações que estão carregadas no dataset, para uma outra estrutra FDMemTable, ou também tens a alternativa de usar o .CloneCursor que também copia a estrutura (Fields) e os dados com a escolha do parâmetro para copiar os eventos de um dataset.

Comment: Desculpe, mas a sua resposta não atende a questão proposta. Mais do que copiar os dados para o FDMemTable, preciso que seja copiada toda a relação Mestre/Detalhe, como é feito no ClientDataSet, quando o DataSetProvider está ligado a duas Queries em uma relação mestre-detalhe. Como isso [aparentemente] não é possível, pensei em fazer manualmente. No entanto, não consigo criar o TDataSetField.